# Generalization in structs - golang

Tags: json, go, struct, generalization

I have this function to read a JSON file into a Driver struct:

```
func getDrivers() []Driver {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/ubuntu/drivers.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var d []Driver
    json.Unmarshal(raw, &d)
    return d
}
```

How can I change this function to also work with a Pilot struct?
I tried using []interface{} without success.

Thank you

Comment: What's the definition of Driver, Pilot, drivers.json, whatever_pilots_is.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of your function to make it generic, and pass the slice as argument. The following should work:

```
func getDriversOrPilots(file string, slice interface{}) {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    json.Unmarshal(raw, slice)
}

func getDrivers() []Driver {
    var d []Driver
    getDriversOrPilots("/home/ubuntu/drivers.json", &d)
    return d
}

func getPilots() []Pilot {
    var p []Pilot
    getDriversOrPilots("/home/ubuntu/pilots.json", &p)
    return p
}
```

Comment: You forgot to remove return type from getDriversOrPilots().